# IPython notebook Jupyter cannot download as .py

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

After I open Jupyter and write down codes, I want to download it as .py file, but it is always downloaded as HTML. How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using safari ? If so complain to Apple.

Comment: I switch to Chrome, and it works! Thanks Matt!

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing the web page and download as .py should show up.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to zoom out on your browser in order to see the options below `html`.  With jupyter notebook, if the browser is zoomed in then some options may fall off the bottom of the browser.

[image]